# Linux Sed and line break to add licence in php files

Tags: linux, replace, sed

In order to add a licence to all php files, I would like to change `<?php` by:

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016-2017 My Project
 * This file is part of My Project 1.2, more information at https://websitemyproject.com
 * Licence another line 
 * Last line of licence
 */
```

So I tested with sed on one file, for the first line of the licence:

```
sed -i -- 's/<?php/<?php\n\/*\n * Copyright(c) 2016-2017 My Project \n *\/ /g' index.php
```

It works but it adds some `^M` at the end of each line of the file index.php and I don't understand why.

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright(c) 2016-2017 My Project
 */ ^M
^M
^M
$page = 'home';^M
^M
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can insert `s/\r//;`  to delete a carriage return chars with your sed command

```
sed -i -- 's/\r//;s/<?php/<?php\n\/*\n * Copyright(c) 2016-2017 My Project \n *\/ /g' index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file has Windows line endings (`^M^J`), your `sed` command is outputting Unix line endings (`^J`), and the result is a mixture of both.

In other words, it might *look* like `sed` is adding `^M` to each line, but actually those `^M` characters were already there. Your editor probably auto-detects the line-endings, and the mixed file is producing mixed results.

You can convert the line endings using a tool like `dos2unix`, or you can tell your `sed` command to output Windows style line endings by using `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Strange, I am under Windows 10 but I use emacs 25.1.1 as text editor.